# Memory manager for cross DLL allocation/deallocation

Tags: memory-management, dll

Resolved: well after few experimentations it seems to be possible.

I was wondering if it's possible to avoid the common cross-dll allocation/deallocation issue by having a memory manager coming along overloaded memory functions (new, delete, delete[], malloc()... ) and responsible for any allocation/deallocation that can occur anywhere in the program, thereby ensuring consistency.

Let's say a.dll contain the memory manager, with something like:

```
class EXPORT MemoryManager
{
    static void* Allocation( size_t uiSize );
    static void  Deallocation( void* pAllocated );
};

inline void* operator new( size_t uiSize )
{
    return MemoryManager::Allocation( uiSize );
}

inline void operator delete( void* pAllocated )
{
    MemoryManager::Deallocation( pAllocated );
}
```

And anywhere else, including b.dll:

```
int* piDummy = ExternalDllFunctionCallingNew();
delete piDummy;
```

Would it solve the problem ?

Comment: Having a memory manager is the *cause* of the problem.  With each module using their own.  Classically by giving a DLL its own version of the CRT.  Just stay out of trouble and write functions that don't require their caller to release memory, pass a pointer to a buffer instead.

Comment: Take a look at how Windows handles resources. E.g. OpenFile/CloseHandle.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, i got that thing with the CRT. But it's possible to do pointer dereferencing and pointer copy on any pointer. So why is my snippet not maintaining consistency ? Aka, where am i using different CRT ? I might not have been totaly clear here. What i'm saying is why can't i use a common class througt several dlls to allocate/deallocate. Thus using the same CRT heap manager.

Comment: Well, you can make it work like that.  But if you have the power to force every DLL to use the exact same memory manager then you also have the power to ensure that all these DLLs use the exact same shared CRT version.  Which is the simpler way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may be misunderstanding the problem. The problem isn't just several DLLs, the problem is mixing different memory managers. Specifically, problems occur when a the allocator used to free some block is distinct from the allocator which originally allocated that block. One common problem is the two allocators expecting different metadata layout (e.g. where the size of the block is stored). Your "solution" just adds another memory manager to the mix, so it only adds *more* possibilities for allocation and deallocation being done by different memory managers. **Edit:** *If* you can enforce that *all* memory allocation and deallocation uses your memory manager which is confined within a single DLL, it will probably work just fine. However, as Hans Passant noted in the comments, if you can enforce that you can most likely also enforce that all components use the same CRT version.

DLLs are only associated with this problem because most memory allocation happens via memory managers provided by the C or C++ run time, and those commonly differ (even more so than the rest of the run time libraries) depending on how the DLL was compiled. You can successfully allocate and deallocate across DLL boundaries if you're careful, and you can get similar problems within a single DLL.

Comment: Again, the whole idea is to always use the same allocator/deallocator. The sole instance responsible for that task would be in one of the dlls. Therefore i don't get why the problem would arise. Btw, i've already written what i'm talking about, and i pretty sure it's working because my unit test fail on the heap validation if i don't use the manager.

Comment: @AdrianGoudard That assumes *every* allocation goes through your allocator. Can you enforce that? I wouldn't assume that.

Comment: Yes, i can enforce that because every STL container has to use my custom allocator/deleter and i'm monitoring every call to allocation/deallocation functions.

Comment: Good point. Well i have the power to make everything go throught that manager with little effort. But i guess performances would be better with the multithreaded CRT right ?